# Query returning data size larger than truncationmaxsize limit

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have an application insights Kusto query where the data size returned is larger than my truncationmaxsize limit. Is there a reason why this is happening? I am trying to cap the data returned to be less than 8Mb. I've added
`| summarize Total=sum(estimate_data_size(*))`

at the end of my query and it shows me 10.7Mb returned. Why is this happening and how do I fix this? Truncationmaxrecords seems to work, but truncationmaxsize is not working for me.

Original query:

```
set truncationmaxsize=8000000; union (traces | extend details = dynamic(null)), (exceptions | project timestamp, operation_Id, name = iff(isnotempty(innermostType), innermostType, outerType), message = iff(isnotempty(innermostMessage), innermostMessage, outerMessage), details) | where timestamp >= datetime(2022-07-06T22:28:43.539650600) | as main | project operation_Id, operation_Name, Timestamp = timestamp, SeverityLevel = severityLevel, Name = name, Message = message | where Message contains 'Job failed. Error:' | summarize arg_max(Timestamp, *) by operation_Id | join kind=leftouter (main | project operation_Id, except_timestamp=timestamp, except_severityLevel = severityLevel, except_Message = message | where (isempty(except_severityLevel) and except_Message !contains "retry") | summarize arg_max(except_timestamp, *) by operation_Id) on operation_Id | join kind=leftouter (main | project operation_Id, dt_message = message, dt_timestamp = timestamp | where dt_message contains 'Type Data' or dt_message contains 'Type: Data' or dt_message contains 'Execute data' | summarize arg_max(dt_timestamp, *) by operation_Id | extend data_type = extract(@"(?:Type|Type:|Execute)\s*((?i)data\s*\w+)", 1, dt_message) | project operation_Id, dt_timestamp, dt_message, failed_on = data_type) on operation_Id | join kind=leftouter (main | project operation_Id, activity_number_message = message, anm_timestamp = timestamp | where activity_number_message contains 'Processing activity' | summarize arg_max(anm_timestamp, *) by operation_Id | project operation_Id, anm_timestamp, activity_number_message) on operation_Id | top 1000 by Timestamp asc | summarize Total=sum(estimate_data_size(*))
```

Comment: I just realized that truncationmaxsize works. The result of 10.7Mb itself doesn't take 10.7Mb of data to display. Ignore the question, this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that truncationmaxsize works. The result of 10.7Mb itself doesn't take 10.7Mb of data to display. Ignore the question, this is solved.